# ActiveProjectLocation.Name of Revit links inside Revit links

Tags: python, revit-api

I open file A, which has x files B linked into it.
Files B also has x files C linked into it. I want to know the name of the location of files C.

I use dynamo for revit to collect RevitLinkInstances (B) in file A and then the previous RevitLinkInstances (B) to collect their RevitLinkInstances (C). That part works well, can be done with custom nodes or python. From there I can collect any number of Project Information from C RevitLinkInstances(in their saved state when I last opened C RevitLinkInstancesfrom my understanding)

I get everything I want so far from the C RevitLinkInstances without opening them in background: File name, instance name, Pinned status, design option, workset of instance, workset of type.

When I try to collect the ActiveProjectLocation.Name of my C files I get nulls, and when I try to GetDocument() just before, same result. It seems logical if that info is not stored in B RevitLinkInstances.

[Image of Dynamo Script](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business6/uploads/dynamobim/original/3X/1/f/1fe93a54d4d57419c2aaac5f69f18104d8dec5d4.png)

I used the following python for my C RevitLinkInstances
and first describe my issue here https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/get-project-location-name-of-revit-links-in-revit-links-inception-like-question

```py
import clr

# clr.AddReference loads and imports .net assembly(dll) as python module
# load RevitAPI.dll and RevitServices.dll
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")

# import filtered element collector and revit link instance classes
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, RevitLinkInstance

# import document manager
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager

# collect link documents from current document
link_docs = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
#rvtLinks = link_docs.ToElements()

ProjectLocation = []

#Queries


for i in link_docs :

    projloc = i.GetLinkDocument().ActiveProjectLocation.Name


#Append Output Lists    

    ProjectLocation.Add(projloc)


OUT = ProjectLocation
```

1. Is it possible to get the ActiveProjectLocation.Name of C RevitLinkInstances?
2. What amount of info can I fetch @ C level without opening the file in background?
3. Is it an API limitation or just a file data storage limitation?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question was already discussed in depth in the [dynamobim forum](https://forum.dynamobim.com) thread on [getting project location name of Revit links in Revit links](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/get-project-location-name-of-revit-links-in-revit-links-inception-like-question/39461).

As far as I am aware, Brendan_Cassidy's initial answer in that thread is perfectly accurate:

- You basically need to get each link as its own document then do a get these revit links from that linked document. I think this post will help you get towards your goal...

I suggest you follow his advice and recursively open each link as a separate document to retrieve the required information from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is kind of half of it. the three questions in this topic remain unanswered.It is not so much as of how to achieve it, I got that part where I could open in background and fetch what I need, this is the easy but long way. But it does not tell me why.

Comment: I'm sorry the answer is incomplete. However, knowing 'why' will hardly help. 'How' is indeed pertinent, of course.